# How to add a Footer in my RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview that allows the user to add data into it rather than having a list already made. Now I want to add a Footer that always shows on the recyclerview even if its empty. My problem is that my recycler view is not showing the second layout

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mDataSet;

private class VIEWS_TYPES{
    public static final int Normal=1;
    public static final int Footer =2;
}

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> mDataSet){
    this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
}

@Override
public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rowView;
    switch (viewType){
        case VIEWS_TYPES.Normal:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row,parent,false);
            break;
        case VIEWS_TYPES.Footer:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_button_recyclerview,parent,false);
            break;
        default:
    }       rowView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(rowView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTitle.setText(mDataSet.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}
```

I think I have to do something with my getItemViewType but I have no idea how to do it. I'm Also not sure if that's the only problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are insanely dozens of posts that explain this, here at SO and if you use any search engine.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I cant seem to find any particular to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if (position < mDataSet.size() - 1) {
          // content
          return VIEWS_TYPES.Normal;
     } else {
          // footer
          return VIEWS_TYPES.Footer;
     }
}
```

and since you have mDataSet.size() + 1 (your footer row)

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size() + 1;
}
```

Update the `onBindViewHolder`

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
if(mDataSet.size()<position)
        holder.mTitle.setText(mDataSet.get(position));
else
// it's code for footer

    }
```

You have to take two different `ViewHolder` for `Content` and `Footer`.

Comment: This makes my app crash in my logs it says Index out of boundsException

Comment: I tried removing the +1 to mdataset.size in the getItemCount and it works but it doesnt show the Footer

Comment: @Kristofer edited! thank to JZM

Comment: I got it Thank you guys so much

Comment: Hold up, I didnt notice this but instead of adding the text that I got from my EditText it just adds an empty item

Comment: One problem with the code is that in the OnBindViewHolder the (mDataset.size() should be >position rather than <position but other than that it works perfectly